# Send data from local storage to online database

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I have data in my local storage, what is best way to send data to my online MSSQL database with web service?

Comment: **1)** Get data in Javascript variable. **2)** Send data to server using [AJAX](www.w3schools.com/ajax) **3)** Update database from server.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla  Tnx, any example online?

Comment: For that, you must tell which programming language are you using on server? Is it JSP, PHP, ASP.NET, Node.js ?

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla  ASP.NET

Comment: [MSSql with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx), [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do an ajax `POST` request. Previously on your server you should have an Rest Service wich receive for example `User` params to store on database.

You can make `POST` request like this.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/services/user/",
        data: {userName:"Sapikelio"}
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.status)
        }
    });
```

And Rest service.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addUser(
        @FormParam("userName") String userName){

    //Store user in db. fe: userDAO.add(userName);

    if (/*Store failed*/)
        return Response.serverError().build();

    //if Store success
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to store something like an arrayList of String.

```
var userList=["user1","user2","user3"];  
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/services/user/",
    data: {users:userList}
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.status)
    }
});
```

Rest service.

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addUser(
            @FormParam("users") List<String> userList){

    for (String value: userList){
    //Store user in db. fe: userDAO.add(value);
    }
    if (/*Store failed*/)
        return Response.serverError().build();

    //if Store success
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
}
```

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Tnx, but how from local storage table generate Json data object and that object send in stored procedure.

Comment: What objetc do you want to store?

Comment: I need generate json format from local storage table and that json sting put in stored procedure in your example ex. @FormParam("userName"), or any other solution?

Comment: On Ajax request , anything you put on `data` attribute is parsed as `Json`. You can put basic data like `strings` etc. and even `objects`

Comment: Then your Rest service parse received `Json` as type you declared here `@FormParam("userName") String userName`

Comment: I don't understend how get local storage table data in one string?

Comment: You parse local storage table data as an Array or any type of datastructure.

Comment: I understend your example, but how get var userList = local storage table users

Comment: Where you have table users? Mysql? xml file? Html table?

Comment: The table users is in web sql local storage